securing ethereum wallet through firewall
I want to secure my wallet ethereum communication through iptables.
how can i obtain a list of ethereum network ip's/ports/protocols, so i make sure my wallet can only connect to those ip's/ports/protocols?

You can start with geth documentation https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options, then do something similar for the consensus layer client.
